# Romance... Despair... Nutcracker?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Here is a five letter word: #####

> It's romantic to have a #####.
>
> It's depressing to be #####ed.
>
> A nutcracker's job's to #####.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word is

> '**CRUSH**'

---

It's romantic to have a #####.

> **Crush** - as in someone you like

It's depressing to be #####ed.

> To be **crush**ed - to be let down

A nutcracker's job's to #####.

> To **crush** - as in crack

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Beastly Gerbil is almost certainly the intended one, but...

The word could equivalently be:

> '**CRACK**'

---

It's romantic to have a #####.

> **Crack** - many people find [image] to be quite attractive!

It's depressing to be #####ed.

> **Crack**s in pavement, among other things, become depressed (depressions): [image]

A nutcracker's job's to #####.

> To **crack** nuts, quite literally!

Comment: "Equivalently" is a bit of a stretch, as is your answer.